# TypeError: SimpleSchema is not a constructor in Meteor 1.6 project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, meteor, simpl-schema

I am creating a SimpleSchema for my staff collection in Meteor and I am getting error "TypeError: SimpleSchema is not a constructor" in my server console. I've gone through the SimpleSchema documentation and this constructor is there, my code is same as their example. Not sure why this error is coming.

Server console Error

```
W20180516-23:44:46.314(2)? (STDERR) /Users/anarayan/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.6.1_1.1rttc72.ip8ui++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20180516-23:44:46.315(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20180516-23:44:46.315(2)? (STDERR)                         ^
W20180516-23:44:46.316(2)? (STDERR) 
W20180516-23:44:46.316(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: SimpleSchema is not a constructor
W20180516-23:44:46.316(2)? (STDERR)     at Staffs.js (imports/api/Staffs/Staffs.js:20:17)
W20180516-23:44:46.317(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180516-23:44:46.317(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180516-23:44:46.318(2)? (STDERR)     at methods.js (imports/api/Staffs/methods.js:1:193)
W20180516-23:44:46.318(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180516-23:44:46.318(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180516-23:44:46.319(2)? (STDERR)     at api.js (imports/startup/both/api.js:1:67)
W20180516-23:44:46.319(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180516-23:44:46.319(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180516-23:44:46.320(2)? (STDERR)     at index.js (imports/startup/server/index.js:1:50)
W20180516-23:44:46.320(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180516-23:44:46.320(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180516-23:44:46.321(2)? (STDERR)     at main.js (server/main.js:1:14)
W20180516-23:44:46.321(2)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:343:9)
W20180516-23:44:46.321(2)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180516-23:44:46.322(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anarayan/project/BusApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:7391:1
W20180516-23:44:46.323(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anarayan/project/BusApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:411:36
W20180516-23:44:46.323(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180516-23:44:46.323(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anarayan/project/BusApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
W20180516-23:44:46.324(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anarayan/project/BusApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
W20180516-23:44:46.324(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/Users/anarayan/project/BusApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20180516-23:44:46.324(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/anarayan/project/BusApp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
```

and Here is the class

```
/* eslint-disable consistent-return */

import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'simpl-schema';

const Staffs = new Mongo.Collection('staffs');

Staffs.allow({
  insert: () => false,
  update: () => false,
  remove: () => false,
});

Staffs.deny({
  insert: () => true,
  update: () => true,
  remove: () => true,
});

Staffs.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Staff Name',
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Staff email id',
  },
  mobile: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Staff mobile number',
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Staff Status',
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Role name',
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    label: 'Location from where staff belongs',
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: String,
    label: 'The date this document was created.',
    autoValue() {
      if (this.isInsert) return (new Date()).toISOString();
    },
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: String,
    label: 'The date this document was last updated.',
    autoValue() {
      if (this.isInsert || this.isUpdate) return (new Date()).toISOString();
    },
  },
});

Staffs.attachSchema(Staffs.schema);

export default Staffs;
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Can you link the doc?

Comment: SimpleSchema documentation - https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js#defining-a-schema

Comment: Can you show use the meteor and npm packages installed in your project ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the package **without curly brackets** because it is exported to the public [as default export](https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js/blob/master/package/lib/main.js):

```
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
```

Because of this you could even import it this way:

```
import MyRenamedSchema from 'simpl-schema';
```

Which could then be called by the other named constructor `new MyRenamedSchema`

**Resources**

Quick start of the documentation:

https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js/blob/master/README.md#quick-start

Export types:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer for those coming here and already have un-curly-braced their import. It seems that if you already have data in your database this also occurs.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52579056/204658

Answer (score -1):

You need to add below packages in your .meteor/packages to use the SimpleSchema constructor.

```
aldeed:collection2
aldeed:simple-schema
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Hi @Ahman the Meteor Package `aldeed:simple-schema` is considered as outdated by the author and it is highly recommended to switch to the npm package.

Comment: I am not sure how this answer got an upvote? `simple-schema` is outdated.