# SimpleSchema is not a constructor

Tags: meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

My app constantly crashes with this error. `TypeError: SimpleSchema is not a constructor at attendances.js (imports/api/attendances/attendances.js:44:27)`. I've googled it and the StackOverflow solution doesn't work. I'm running [simpl-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js#installation) and [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

const Attendances = new Mongo.Collection('attendances');

Attendances.debug = true;
Attendances.allow({
  insert: () => true,
  update: () => true,
  remove: () => true,
});

Attendances.deny({
  insert: () => false,
  update: () => false,
  remove: () => false,
});

const AttendancesSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
  },
}, {
  clean: {
    filter: true,
    autoConvert: true,
    removeEmptyStrings: true,
    trimStrings: true,
    getAutoValues: true,
  },
});

Attendances.attachSchema(AttendancesSchema);

export default Attendances;
```

This is the full error message in my terminal.

Path: `ERROR MESSAGE`

```
W20180620-21:07:11.542(10)? (STDERR) TypeError: SimpleSchema is not a constructor
W20180620-21:07:11.542(10)? (STDERR)     at attendances.js (imports/api/attendances/attendances.js:44:27)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at publications.js (imports/api/userProfiles/server/publications.js:1:354)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at register-api.js (imports/startup/server/register-api.js:1:195)
W20180620-21:07:11.543(10)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180620-21:07:11.544(10)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180620-21:07:11.544(10)? (STDERR)     at index.js (imports/startup/server/index.js:1:50)
W20180620-21:07:11.544(10)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180620-21:07:11.544(10)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180620-21:07:11.544(10)? (STDERR)     at main.js (server/main.js:1:14)
W20180620-21:07:11.544(10)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:339:7)
W20180620-21:07:11.545(10)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:238:16)
W20180620-21:07:11.545(10)? (STDERR)     at /Users/blakepascoe/Documents/dev/roll_call/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:1725:1
```

Comment: Which simple-schema version do you use?

Comment: simpl-schema: "version": "1.5.0"  https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js

Comment: Does it work with 1.4.3? There have been several issues reported with >1.5.0

Comment: Nope I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I've added the full terminal message above. @Jankapunkt

Comment: Ok, so I reset the app and it works fine. No idea why I needed to do that.

Comment: Maybe this was rather an issue with Mongo and Collection2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the suggested fix [in the comment by @bp123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946918/simpleschema-is-not-a-constructor#comment88913467_50946918) that you should reset the Meteor project, and that fixed it for me too.

So I'm turning that comment into an answer:

*Reset your project.*

It does not seem impossible that a schema need to be added before any data is put in the database, but I'm very confused why this applies even for creating a Schema without attaching it to anything.