# What causes the SimpleSchema is not a constructor error at collections.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, simpl-schema

When using `simpl-schema` I am getting the following error:

```
SimpleSchema is not a constructor
```

I have already added

```
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2@3.0.0
"simpl-schema": "^1.4.3"
```

My code:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';    
import  SimpleSchema  from 'simpl-schema';     
export const Books = new Mongo.Collection("books");     
const Book = new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Title",
        max: 200
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        label: "Author"
    },
    copies: {
        type: SimpleSchema.Integer,
        label: "Number of copies",
        min: 0
    },
    lastCheckedOut: {
        type: Date,
        label: "Last date this book was checked out",
        optional: true
    },
    summary: {
        type: String,
        label: "Brief summary",
        optional: true,
        max: 1000,
        optional: true
    }
});
Books.attachSchema(Book);
```

What's causing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Everything seems correct, just the "simpl-schema": "^1.4.3" should be aldeed:simpl-schema   in your .meteor/packages  file

Comment: At first I added that package. It didn't workout.

Comment: @AmarPathak, `aldeed:simpl-schema` is deprecated and _does not_ work with `collection2@3.0.0`. @NimmiVerma have you checked that `simple-schema` exists in `/node_modules/simpl-schema`? maybe delete `node_modules` and re-install?

Comment: The most common cause of these errors are either a typo in the import statement or failed npm install

Comment: I have this too. And yes, `node_modules/simpl-schema` contains SimpleSchema.js. Some other package I used returned undefined for its exports in insecure mode, because it was only designed to work on the server. Could that be it?

Comment: There is one answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/52579056/204658.